# iOS - Controls have incorrect coordinates on device

Tags: ios, ios8

I have a view with some controls and having problems when working with coordinates.

All of this code gets executed in **- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated**

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
NSLog(@"Screen - x:%f y:%f width:%f height:%f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);

rect = self.view.frame;
NSLog(@"View - x:%f y:%f width:%f height:%f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);

NSLog(@"Nav Bar - x:%f y:%f width:%f height:%f", self.navigationBar.frame.origin.x, self.navigationBar.frame.origin.y, self.navigationBar.frame.size.width, self.navigationBar.frame.size.height);

NSLog(@"Button - x:%f y:%f width:%f height:%f", self.btn.frame.origin.x, self.btn.frame.origin.y, self.btn.frame.size.width, self.btn.frame.size.height);
```

And the log output:

```
Screen  - x:  0.000000 y:  0.000000 width:320.000000 height:568.000000
View    - x:  0.000000 y:  0.000000 width:320.000000 height:568.000000
Nav Bar - x:  0.000000 y:  8.000000 width:600.000000 height: 44.000000
Button  - x:246.000000 y:542.000000 width: 50.000000 height: 50.000000
```

Not quite sure how the **Nav Bar** can be wider than the **device**, or how the **Buttons y coordinates** can extend beyond the bottom of the screen: **(542 + 50) > 568**, and yet the entire button does get displayed on the screen of the device.

It seems like the **Nav Bar** and **Button** coordinates are getting pulled from the values in **Interface Builder** but they are clearly incorrect when running on an actual device.

These incorrect values are really causing me problems when placing some programmatically created items on the screen.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I can understand it's autolayout that is causing you these problems. You need to add constraints to these controls in order to identify their correct position while rendering UI.

Comment: I am using constraints and I am not getting any complaints about them.

Comment: You can break view in xcode 6 and get more information about the layout of your element on the view at runtime.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are talking about. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the view is not laid out when **viewDidLoad** or **viewWillAppear** get called.

Accessing the frame in **viewDidLayoutSubviews** returned the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the Size Class.
It is mandatory when you are using Size Class you must use the Auto layout.

Comment: I am using auto layout for all controls.

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints are possibly not correct enough to keep these controls laid out correctly.

Comment: I'm not getting any messages about constraint problems when I execute the code, and no warnings are displayed when editing the .xib

Comment: Problems are only reported when you have not added enough constraints or added too many constraints. Make sure the resulting frame is not outside the bounds by using the live view debugger.

Answer (score 0):

[image: screenshot of Debug view hierarchy button]

See the next to last button (two overlapping rectangles), this is Debug view hierarchy button. Once your view is loaded in the window, you can click this button to debug the view hierarchy. In the view hierarchy you can see where your control is placed and then you can figure out what is wrong with the position.

Then you can play with your constraints to get the right position.

Comment: This was helpful,  but not the issue, although knowing this will be useful for the future. Thanks